# Is it true that for any cardinal $\kappa$ that in injects into $\aleph_{\omega}$, $(\kappa)^{+}$ injects into $\aleph_{\omega}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Here, $(\kappa)^+$ is the Hartog's Number, the least cardinal $\lambda$ so that there is no injection from $\lambda$ to $\kappa$.

My feeling is that this is true, since for any ordinal $\alpha < \omega $, 
 $\ \alpha+1<\omega$, so for each infinite cardinal $\aleph_\alpha<\aleph_\omega$, $\ \aleph_{\alpha+1}=(\aleph_{\alpha})^+<\aleph_\omega$, but I feel I am making some leaps in logic here or have missed something and this doesn't constitute any kind of a proof.

Comment: Doesn't $\aleph_\omega$ inject into $\aleph_\omega$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $\aleph_\alpha<\aleph_\omega\implies\aleph_{\alpha+1}<\aleph_\omega$ - this is true simply because $\omega$ is a limit ordinal - but "$\aleph_\alpha$ injects into $\aleph_\omega$" does *not* imply $\aleph_\alpha<\aleph_\omega$ (e.g. $\aleph_\omega$ injects into $\aleph_\omega$, obviously).

Comment: Ah yes, I see. How would you find an example of a cardinal with this property?

Comment: @Matthew No cardinal has that property: $\kappa$ always injects into $\kappa$.

Comment: Would it be true instead for the well ordering on ordinals i.e. If $\kappa<\aleph_\omega$, then $(\kappa)^+<\aleph_\omega$? Since in this case $\aleph_\omega$ is not strictly less than itself?

Comment: @Matthew Yes. You can also phrase it in terms of cardinalities the same way.

Comment: @Matthew And note that you can turn that into an embedding-phrased condition: if $\kappa$ injects *as a proper initial segment* of $\aleph_\omega$, then $\kappa^+<\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: Yes. This is what I had originally intended to ask about but I forgot that a<b implies a injects into b for cardinals is not an iff statement